# How to find a repeating playlist

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem on TestDome env.

PROBLEM: A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to None.

Implement a function is_repeating_playlist that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.

For example, the following code prints "True" as both songs point to each other.

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
    
first.next_song(second)
second.next_song(first)
    
print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

The full code is as follows:

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.next = None

    def next_song(self, song):
        self.next = song 
    
    def is_repeating_playlist(self):
        """
        :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
        """
        print (self.next.next.name)
        if self.next.next is self :
            return "True"
        else:
            return "False"
     
            
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
    
first.next_song(second)
second.next_song(first)
    
print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

I still get "WRONG ANSWER". What am I misssing here?

Comment: Should it print `"True"` or `True`?

Comment: `if self.next.next is self` is only going to work if there two songs pointing to each other. With three songs, this may not work.

Comment: It's weird to implement your own linked list in Python, but it's not hard to find existing questions about detecting cycles in linked lists in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your example that you can easily fix:

- You are not returning a boolean but a string, just change the output
- It won't work for more than two songs, you should iterate on all the next songs in your playlist

My suggested correction goes like this:

```
def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    """
    :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
    """
    print (self.next.next.name)
    currentSong = self
    while (currentSong.next) is not None :
        currentSong = currentSong.next
        if (currentSong is self):
            return True
    return False
```

And for an example with 3 songs, it has the following behaviour:

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
third = Song("Holy Diver")

first.next_song(second)
second.next_song(third)
third.next_song(first)

print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

output:

```
Holy Diver
true
```